Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: apache). Failed to verify the temporary Apache configuration changes
Am trying getting ssl certificate using letsencrypt and certbot with apache on my Ubuntu server for mydomain.com am getting the error using command sudo certbot --apache -d mydomain.com am getting error
The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary Apache configuration changes made by Certbot.

i tried tried to update sudo apt update then sudo apt install certbot and run again sudo certbot --apache -d mydomain.com still i got the same error.

Please either post a real answer to your question and accept that (if you think such answer is of worth for others coming over your question here), or delete the question. Thanks!

i solved this by use the command
sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns -d mydomain.com

where by i added TXT records on dns configuration for verification and waited till i verified my records are saved via
https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#TXT/_acme-challenge.mydomain.com
do not forget to replace mydomain.com with you respect domain
